# How can I use a json with flask_login.login_user

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-login

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = {
            "email": str(email),
            "password": str(password)
        }
        res = post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login", json=user)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            login_user(user, remember=True)  #here is my problem
            return redirect(url_for('products', pag=1))
        else:
            flash('Error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

How can I use login_user if I'm using a rest-api to get the user, and it return me a json?
I know flask_login uses a python-object, but my var res it return me a json not a python object.
I'm working with JWT at the rest-api, so my var res is just a JWT.

Comment: before I go into an answer, what you need here is to authenticate a user using JWT and then you are expecting to get this user object, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just perform the login business logic under this `login` route but chose to call some other API endpoint? Also, you might return just the User object from that endpoint you are using and pass it to `login_user()`. The issue is that you provided little details. Please show what is going under `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login` but also your User Model. That would help to provide a good and useful answer.